# Why apache log "(111)Connection refused" warning when child process is closed

Tags: linux, vpn, apache-http-server, firewall, process

I am running a server using apache, and the apache error log is periodically getting this warning, usually when there are visits to the site, and usually in groups of at least two or three at a time.

```
[Sun Nov 22 15:23:59.570652 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4542] (111)Connection refused: AH00056: connect to listener on [::]:80
```

pid 4542 is the parent process for apache. I'm curious what is causing these warnings, whether they are indicative of a problem, and what I can do to prevent them from filling up the apache error log.

I have already done some testing and research, and I have some ideas about what might be going on. The most useful thing so far has been enabling trace8 logging for apache, which revealed that each "(111)Connection refused" warning was followed by the closing of an apache child process. When there are a group of the warning, the first one or two will be followed immediately by the closure of an apache child process, and then subsequent warning will have a delay of as long as 12 seconds before a child process is closed. And then within a minute of the last process closing, new ones will have open to fill the vacated slots. Here is a log excerpt of one round of the entire process:

```
[Sun Nov 22 15:23:59.570652 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4542] (111)Connection refused: AH00056: connect to listener on [::]:80
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:01.570677 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4542] (111)Connection refused: AH00056: connect to listener on [::]:80
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:01.570721 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5760 (gen 2/slot 11) exited 
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:03.570674 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4542] (111)Connection refused: AH00056: connect to listener on [::]:80
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:05.570674 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4542] (111)Connection refused: AH00056: connect to listener on [::]:80
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:05.570712 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5762 (gen 2/slot 12) exited
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:07.570703 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4542] (111)Connection refused: AH00056: connect to listener on [::]:80
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:13.576458 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5701 (gen 2/slot 1) exited
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:14.577507 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5703 (gen 2/slot 7) exited
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:17.580632 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5712 (gen 2/slot 6) exited
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:46.608431 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5800 (gen 2/slot 1) started
[Sun Nov 22 15:24:49.611368 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5802 (gen 2/slot 6) started
[Sun Nov 22 15:26:16.699374 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5851 (gen 2/slot 7) started
[Sun Nov 22 15:26:17.701274 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5852 (gen 2/slot 11) started
[Sun Nov 22 15:26:17.701821 2015] [core:trace4] [pid 4542] mpm_common.c(534): mpm child 5853 (gen 2/slot 12) started
```

Based on reading about similar errors, I get the impression that the warning is from some problem when the apache parent process is (attempting to) communicate with the child processes. Apparently that communication is succeeding somehow though, because the child processes are being closed. Assuming this is what is happening (and I'm not sure that it is), I'm still not sure what to do about it.

One aspect of the network configuration on this computer that seems as though it could be relevant is that the connection is through an openVPN-based client called [bitmask](https://bitmask.net/en/help/vpn/linux). It features a firewall configuration that prevents non-encrypted data from being leaked through the network connection, which looks like this:

```
/etc/apache2$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
bitmask    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain bitmask (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.1.0/24      
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
RETURN     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
RETURN     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anon.riseup.net     
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Any explanations for understanding and/or stopping this log warning are appreciated. Or further tests in that direction. Thank you.